Expression to count related number of owners in parcel layer in QGIS
Scenario: In a polygon layer with construction details (f.e. road, construction site) and one table layer with parcel owner information. Both layers have a column with the parcel_id, because the construction layer was intersected with a parcel layer earlier.
How can I add a column in the construction layer which counts the related number of related owners by parcel_id?

You can use this expression:
aggregate('l2', 'count', "id2", "id2"=attribute(@parent, 'id'))

l2 is the layer you want to count. "id2" is the field in layer l2 and id is the matching field in the first layer.
